# Saving user settings in Metro app using C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to write user selected settings in Metro app, in Local Folder. I have done the code as below, but it is not working.

The code to save settings:

```
        void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        //code to save app settings.
        var localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        localSettings.Values["playerPosition"] = playerPosition;
        localSettings.Values["aiPosition"] = aiPosition;
        localSettings.Values["selectedLevel"] = selectedLevel;
    }
```

The code to read settings:

```
            var localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        if ((localSettings.Values["playerPosition"]) == null)
        {
            localSettings.Values["playerPosition"] = 1;
            localSettings.Values["aiPosition"] = 1;
            localSettings.Values["selectedLevel"] = "1";

            playerPosition = aiPosition = 1;
            selectedLevel = "1";
        }
        else
        {
            playerPosition = (int)localSettings.Values["playerPosition"];
            aiPosition = (int)localSettings.Values["aiPosition"];
            selectedLevel = (string)localSettings.Values["selectedLevel"]; ----
```

Clearly I am supposed to save this localSettings variable in a file. But, I am unable to find the code to do that. Also, is Unload event a good place to do it, or should I move it to OnNavigatedFrom event? Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself yet, but maybe you could check out this sample (App settings sample):
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-settings-sample-1f762f49

It uses the [Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR208189) namespace.

**Edit:**
After reading [this post](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/using-local-storage-with-c-and-xaml-in-windows-8-metro-apps.html) and the [quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361) on MSDN, it seems to me you do not need to save a file, because the LocalSettings handle this for you? Are you not seeing this behavior?

Comment: Trying the very same thing. Sadly, I am unable to see similar behaviour.

Comment: And if you set a breakpoint on the unload handler, it gets hit?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. Yes, it does get hit. I also tried moving it to OnNavigatedFrom. Same result again. BTW, is there any other way to check if file is getting saved somewhere or not.